# Error 404 MyBB Folder inside Wordpress Root Folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, webserver, cpanel, mybb

So I have installed mybb first /bb/ dir then installed wp inside root folder / 
Now when am going on myBB index all images broken and when I browse images it shows WP page not found?!!

Both htaccess WP one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bb/(.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also here is MyBB htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# Some hosts require RewriteBase to make RewriteRules work.
RewriteBase /bb/
# Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://alnassiri.com/bb/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
# Google SEO 404:
ErrorDocument 404 /bb/misc.php?google_seo_error=404
# Google SEO Sitemap:
RewriteRule ^sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# Google SEO URL Forums:
RewriteRule ^Forum\-([^./]+)$ forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# Google SEO URL Threads:
RewriteRule ^Thread\-([^./]+)$ showthread.php?google_seo_thread=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# Google SEO URL Announcements:
RewriteRule ^Announcement\-([^./]+)$ announcements.php?google_seo_announcement=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# Google SEO URL Users:
RewriteRule ^User\-([^./]+)$ member.php?action=profile&google_seo_user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# Google SEO URL Calendars:
RewriteRule ^Calendar\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?google_seo_calendar=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# Google SEO URL Events:
RewriteRule ^Event\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?action=event&google_seo_event=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Note: When I removed mybb htaccess all mybb files changed to page not found!! Also this is an image maybe give you more sense

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after hours of searching, I realized that while uploading plugin files folder permission changed from 755 to 700 which gave me 405 Forbidden error after removing both htaccess. Changing back Perm fixed everything.

Thank you